# Please unmerge history and command-history

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The tag [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has been merged into [command-history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-history). Err, no, that doesn't work. It's used for [history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History) questions as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's unfortunate; hopefully [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) doesn't get used too often where people meant [command-history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-history). I revoked the [command-history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-history) ← [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) synonym, and retagged the ones that were converted incorrectly:

- [Is Linux a Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/is-linux-a-unix)
- [What does “rc” in .bashrc stand for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3467/what-does-rc-in-bashrc-stand-for)
- [Why is there a * When There is Mention of Unix Throughout the Internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/why-is-there-a-when-there-is-mention-of-unix-throughout-the-internet)
- [Anyone know the meaing of yy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/anyone-know-the-meaing-of-yy)
- [Where did the “wheel” group get its name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name)
- [How was the shift to 64 bits handled on Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-was-the-shift-to-64-bits-handled-on-linux)

Good catch

Comment: What about using `unix-history` instead of `history` and blacklisting `history`? When thinking about a shell history in the context of a question, I would never ever notice that the term could be used in other senses, like the classic one...